# Swift: Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'C.IndexDistance'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Since updating my Xcode I have run into this problem with a piece if code that I got from a Udemy Tutorial.

Here is the code:

```
 func shuffle<C: MutableCollection where C.Index == Int>( list: C) -> C {
    var list = list
    let total = list.count

    for i in 0..<(total - 1) {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(total - i))) + i
        guard i != j else { continue }
        swap(&list[i], &list[j])
    }

    return list
}
```

and this line:

```
for i in 0..<(total - 1) {
```

brings this error:

> Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'C.IndexDistance'

Can someone help me with this?